# mapping between ontologies properties

Tags: mapping, ontology

I have three ontologies and I want to define mappings between their properties.
For example there are three properties (2 datatype properties and an objectproperty) in each one of them to define the pedagogical level (the ontologies describe pedagogical resources).
The three properties are:

1. hasContext1 (domain: the resource, range: skos concept (which is a class))
2. hasContext2 (domain: the resource, range: list / xsd:literal)
3. hasContext3 (domain: the resource, range: xsd: string)

Is there any way to map between these three properties?

Thanks
Hiba

Comment: Maybe something like this (in Manchester syntax): `(Teacher that hasContext1 value skos:SuperTeacher) EquivalentTo (Teacher that hasContext3 value "SuperTeacher"^^xsd:string)`. In Protege, you can write it *Active Ontology > General class axioms*.

Comment: There are many things that are unclear in this question: First, what do you mean by "define mappings"? Second, "domain", in standard RDF or OWL  terminology is a class. Is "the resource" a class? Third, "xsd:" is usually used as the prefix for the namespace of XML Schema datatypes. "xsd:literal" is not one of the XML Schema datatypes. Fourth, what does "list / xsd:literal" means? Specifically, what is the meaning of the slash? Fifth, how are the descriptions of the 3 properties related to "pedagogical level"? Is the fact that the ontologies are related to pedagogy relevent to the question?